# server side background process

Tags: .net, server-side

I need to run a method on the server side that gets a stream from a web service. But it should work all the time that server runs. I need to call this method when server is on and it should work until the server is shut down. This shouldn't be up to any client request. What should be the architecture behind this approach? I am using photon socket server with .net but a general idea would be fine too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it needs to run whenever the server is "up", without any user intervention, then it should run as a service.

Create a service project in VS. Create your code as a class library project, which you can easily test, give it a starting method etc and then call it from a service project.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of a class library, you could create an exe with the working code in separate files to test and get running.  Share the working files between the service project and the test application project.